# Services 3 File upload, create/return image styles

Tags: services, media

Ahoy all!

So, long story short, I'm uploading files to drupal through services from an angular app, and getting a response/url/etc no problem. **My question is, how do I enable image styles to be created on REST upload from services?** I'm receiving an empty response in the image_styles array. I am assuming it likely isn't something I need to add into the POST request, but happy to add POST request code if needed.

I am coming up a little short on my google-fu on this one, and any help appreciated!

[image: Screenshot of REST Response, file upload drupal services]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the image created with the style when you request a page displaying that image_style So you have to call it in code.

The default generation method only creates images when they are requested by a user's browser.

**image_style_url**  Returns the URL for an image derivative given a style and image path

code sample :

```
// $file object from file_load($fid) 
image_style_url('style name', $file->uri)
```